# How did I get Ghulvania to Power Level 2, without completing its quests?

Tags: gems-of-war

I came back to Gems of War after years away, and somehow, my Ghulvania passed Power Level 1, the one that, for all the other Kingdoms, needs the Kingdom's quests to be completed.

But, I've barely started the Ghulvania quests, at 2 out of however many battles there are...

---

Does anyone know how I managed that? Were requirements for raising the Power Level, different in the past?

And, can I repeat this glitch? I haven't completed many kingdoms, but I want to get my Power Levels up, without having to do all the quests...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago, [the kingdom power system got a rework](https://community.gemsofwar.com/t/3-5-patch-notes/41212) as part of version 3.5. Any kingdom power obtained before then, were grandfathered in.

Prior to that new system, kingdom power was calculated on the number of troops unlocked in a kingdom, the number of levels the troops in the kingdom had, and the number of traits the troops in the kingdom had.

Levelling and traiting troops used to be hard, but with [the introduction of orbs in 3.3](https://community.gemsofwar.com/t/version-3-3-tomorrow-and-orbs/36014), it became easy. So they needed a new kingdom power system that would incentivise other things than just levelling and traiting.

Here's the full list of kingdom power level tasks, as of current writing:

**Kingdom power level 1 tasks**

1. Collect 2 [kingdom] troops
2. Upgrade a [kingdom] troop to level 5
3. Complete all the Quests

**Kingdom power level 2 tasks**

1. Collect 4 [kingdom] troops
2. Upgrade 3 [kingdom] troops to level 10
3. Level [kingdom] to level 5

**Kingdom power level 3 tasks**

1. Collect a weapon from [kingdom]
2. Unlock 3 Traits on 4 [kingdom] troops
3. Collect 2 Epic troops from [kingdom]

**Kingdom power level 4 tasks**

1. Collect 8 [kingdom] troops
2. Upgrade 5 [kingdom] troops to level 15
3. Upgrade [kingdom] to level 10

**Kingdom power level 5 tasks**

1. Fully upgrade a weapon from [kingdom]
2. Unlock 3 Traits on 7 [kingdom] troops
3. Collect a Legendary troop from [kingdom]

**Kingdom power level 6 tasks**

1. Collect 12 [kingdom] troops
2. Upgrade 9 [kingdom] troops to level 18
3. Complete 7 Tier 2 challenge battles

**Kingdom power level 7 tasks**

1. Collect 3 weapons from [kingdom]
2. Unlock 3 Traits on 11 [kingdom] troops
3. Collect 2 Legendary troops from [kingdom]

**Kingdom power level 8 tasks**

1. Collect 16 [kingdom] troops
2. Upgrade 14 [kingdom] troops to level 19
3. Fully upgrade 2 [kingdom] weapons

**Kingdom power level 9 tasks**

1. Unlock the [kingdom class] class
2. Unlock 3 Traits on 16 [kingdom] troops
3. Collect a pet from [kingdom]

**Kingdom power level 10 tasks**

1. Collect 20 [kingdom] troops
2. Upgrade 18 [kingdom] troops to level 20
3. Collect a Mythic troop from [kingdom]

**Kingdom power level 11 tasks**

1. Upgrade 20 [kingdom] troops to level 20
2. Upgrade the [kingdom class] class to level 20
3. Upgrade a [kingdom] pet to level 10

**Kingdom power level 12 tasks**

1. Unlock 3 Traits on 21 [kingdom] troops
2. Reach Champion Level 20 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Collect 4 [kingdom] weapons

**Kingdom power level 13 tasks**

1. Upgrade 22 [kingdom] troops to level 20
2. Unlock 3 Traits on the [kingdom class] class
3. Upgrade a [kingdom] pet to level 20

**Kingdom power level 14 tasks**

1. Unlock 3 Traits on 23 [kingdom] troops
2. Reach Champion Level 30 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Fully upgrade 3 [kingdom] weapons

**Kingdom power level 15 tasks**

1. Level 24 [kingdom] troops to level 20
2. Reach Champion Level 40 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Collect 2 [kingdom] pets

**Kingdom power level 16 tasks**

1. Unlock 3 Traits on 25 [kingdom] troops
2. Reach Champion Level 50 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Fully upgrade 4 [kingdom] weapons

**Kingdom power level 17 tasks**

1. Upgrade 26 [kingdom] troops to level 20
2. Reach Champion Level 60 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Upgrade 2 [kingdom] pets to level 20

**Kingdom power level 18 tasks**

1. Unlock 3 Traits on 27 [kingdom] troops
2. Reach Champion Level 70 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Fully upgrade 6 [kingdom] weapons

**Kingdom power level 19 tasks**

1. Upgrade 28 [kingdom] troops to level 20
2. Reach Champion Level 80 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Collect 3 [kingdom] pets

**Kingdom power level 20 tasks**

1. Unlock 3 Traits on 29 [kingdom] troops
2. Reach Champion Level 100 on the [kingdom class] class
3. Fully upgrade 8 [kingdom] weapons